# iOS Detect subviews being added to UIViewContoller's view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `scrollView` to which custom views are being added and removed in response to user interaction. I want to make sure the container view is always big enough to display all the subviews, and would like to detect when a view was added or removed. I tried using KVO:

```
[self.scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"subviews" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

But while there was no error, `observeValueForKeyPath:...` method never gets called when the number of subviews change. What should I use instead?

P.S. I know I could put the calculation of desired `contentSize` property directly into the methods that add/remove subviews to scrollView, but for architectural reasons, this option is inferior to me and I'd prefer to something like KVO instead. Are there options like this?

Answer (score 3):

"subviews" is always there when UIView is created, try observing on "subviews.count". Or the better way, use following API from UIView:

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview
```

Please refer to: "Observing View-Related Changes" [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW90).

Comment: Cannot observe `subviews.count` because `NSArray` (that is, `subviews`) does not support KVO. :(

Comment: It's pretty dumb that those methods `didAddSubview:`, `willRemoveSubview:`, etc. aren't in a delegate. They basically are a delegate that's hard-coded set to `self`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't KVO subviews but you can KVO sublayers which will also get called if a subview is added

```
[self.view.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"sublayers" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I kept getting the following error when I tried to use `addObserver(forKeyPath:options:context:)` in Swift:

`An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled`

So I ended-up using the Swift-specific KVO API:

```
token = view.layer.observe(\.sublayers, options: [.old, .new]) { _, change in
    print("Observed: \(change)")
}
```